# how to create transparent arrow with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create arrow in `div` using after in css, but cant make it as required.

This is the example image I am trying to create:

[image: example image of arrow]

This is what I have created, but not sure how to control the background color of arrow

```css
.discount-tag {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background-color: rgba(61,97,153,0.9);
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 7px 22px 7px 10px;
}
.discount-tag:after {
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-right-color: #106199;
 border-width: 17px;
 margin-top: -17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag"> 10% Discount </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may rotate the pseudo and use box-shadow to paint the background of the parent tag.

So you can see through the arrow any plain or complex backgrounds.

Box-shadow can also allow you to draw borders:

```css
.discount-tag {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 7px 32px 7px 10px;/* update */
  overflow:hidden;/* added */
}
.discount-tag:before {
 right: -21px;/* update */
 top: 0;
  bottom:0;/* added */
  width:34px;/* added */
  transform:rotate(45deg);/* added */
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;/* added */
 pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50vw  rgba(61,97,153,0.9)/* added */
    /* border : removed */
}
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800);/* see transparency */
  }

/* extra a border needed ? */
.discount-tag:before {  
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50vw  rgba(61,97,153,0.9), inset 1px -1px white;
  }

  .discount-tag {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px white, -1px -1px white
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag"> 10% Discount </div>
```

If you still want to use border : put pseudo outside :

```css
.discount-tag {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background-color: rgba(61,97,153,0.9);
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 7px  10px;
}
.discount-tag:after {
 left:100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid  rgba(61,97,153,0.9);
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-right-color:transparent;
 border-width: 17px;
  border-left:none;
 margin-top: -17px;
}

body {
 background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800);/* see transparency */
}
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag"> 10% Discount </div>
```

Borders around can also be drawn:

```css
.discount-tag {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 background-color:#3A609B;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 7px  10px;
 
}
.discount-tag:before,.discount-tag:after  {
 left:100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid  #3A609B;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-right-color:transparent;
 border-width: 17px;
  border-left:none;
 margin-top: -17px;
}


body {
 background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800);/* see transparency */
}


/* draw border around ? */
.discount-tag:before {
  border-width:18px;
  margin-top:-18px;
  margin-left:1px;
  border-color:white;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  }
.discount-tag {
  border:1px solid white
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag"> 10% Discount </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with two arrow parts. Set one on `:before` and one on `:after`

```css
.discount-tag {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(61,97,153,0.9);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 7px 22px 7px 10px;
}
.discount-tag:before,
.discount-tag:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -16px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.discount-tag:before {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(61,97,153,0.9) transparent transparent transparent;
}
.discount-tag:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(61,97,153,0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag"> 10% Discount </div>
```

To make it more obvious what's going on here the same but with dummy colors

```css
.discount-tag {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(61,97,153,0.9);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 7px 22px 7px 10px;
}
.discount-tag:before,
.discount-tag:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -16px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.discount-tag:before {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 16px 16px 0 0;
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
}
.discount-tag:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 16px 0 0 16px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag"> 10% Discount </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but actually I have a background image behind this div as you notice in example image, and now that right area is showing white.

Answer (score 2):

You can add 2 pseudos, and skew them to create the tails of the arrow:

```css
.discount-tag {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 7px 22px 7px 10px;
}
.discount-tag:before,
.discount-tag:after {
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
.discount-tag:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: skewX(-35deg);
}
.discount-tag:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: center top;
  transform: skewX(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="discount-tag">10% Discount</div>
```